# Criteria for neighbors when calculating 2D lindemann parameter

Tags: phase-transition

I am trying to compute 2D lindemann parameter to quantify melting in colloidal crystals from particle coordinates obtained in 2D.

The equation I have come across for computing 2D lindemann parameter is as follows

$$L = \frac{\left\langle \left( \Delta u_{i}\left( t \right) -\Delta u_{j}\left( t \right) \right)^{2} \right\rangle}{2a^{2}} $$

where $$\Delta u\left( t \right) = u\left( t \right)-u\left( 0 \right)$$

*i* and *j* are the nearest neighbors, and *a* is the interparticle distance.

Now i am confused as what particles are considered neighbors in the system, is there a fixed cut-off distance that we consider or we take into account the whole system.

Please, if someone could shed some light on this

Posting in physics section as it might be more relevant here

(DOI : https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.2721)